# Simple javascript for html{font-size= x %} changing with resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm in need of a javascript code that will change my html{font-size= x %}. Before, I have done it with CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px)
{
   html { font-size: 62.5%; } 
}
```

for 5 screen sizes. Now I want to change my text size in real time when I change the resolution of browser window.

Thank you so much guys. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: doesn't css change it in realtime?

Comment: sure thing, but i meant that it will not change only when i pass 950,720,480 pixels but when i resize it by one pixel. You are right it is changing in realtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this jquery function

```
$( window ).resize(function() {});
```

So this will trigger the function each time the window is resized. All you need to do is figure out the math you're going to use to determine the font-size. Once you've added the math in, you can use this to modify the css:

```
$(body).css( "font-size", X );
```

X will be the result of your math.

So your resulting code should look something like this:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
   var x = window.size * Some math you need to figure out;
   $(body).css( "font-size", X );
});
```

Note: To use this you need to call a jQuery library.